# Different result when selecting different columns ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am querying multiple databases with heidiSQL and I am obtaining a different result when i adjust the SELECT clause.

When I execute the following query, the db returns 501 records:

```
select *
from klantcontact 
inner join (
select top 448 ks.FIRNR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FIRNR DESC) as rownum
from klant ks) res
on klantcontact.KLANR = res.FIRNR
```

I actully only need two columns. But i get 526 records as result when I run the following query (only the select clause is changed):

```
select klantcontact.NAAM
from klantcontact 
inner join (
select top 448 ks.FIRNR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FIRNR DESC) as rownum
from klant ks) res
on klantcontact.KLANR = res.FIRNR
```

I think it has something to do with the 'OVER'?

Comment: You seem to be using a `TOP` with out an `ORDER BY`. That, effectively, means you are asking the SQL Server to *"return 448 random rows from the table `klant`"*. When ever you use a `TOP` **always** include an `ORDER BY` to ensure you get consistant results.

Answer (score 0):

In the subquery, you have specified top 448 but you have not specified any order by clause at the end. So every time you run a query there is a chance that the 448 rows which are returned are different giving a different number of rows every time.

Change your query to either the following:

```
select klantcontact.NAAM
from klantcontact 
inner join (
select top 448 ks.FIRNR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FIRNR DESC) as rownum
from klant ks order by ks.FIRNR) res
on klantcontact.KLANR = res.FIRNR
```

OR remove the top 448 clause.